# how to rename all variables in a list of data

Tags: r

I try to use `map` to process a list of data.frame. My goals is: if names of Data[[]] %in% `datamap$col.name`, then rename it as `datamap$VAR`. My codes and error message are:

[image]

What did I do wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: Please read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular post reproducible examples using dpout and do not use images since it means no one can run the example other than you without tediously retyping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `for` loop, use `rename` with a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
Data1 <-  map(Data, ~ 
          {datamap_sub <- datamap %>% 
                            filter(col_name %in% names(.x))
        .x %>%
            rename(!!! setNames(datamap_sub$col_name, datamap_sub$VAR))
            })
```

-output

```
#[[1]]
#   SL Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width     Sp
#1 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa
#2 4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 setosa
#3 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
#4 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa
#5 5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa
#6 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa

#[[2]]
#                  mpg_new cyl disp  hp drat wt_new  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4            21.0   6  160 110 3.90  2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag        21.0   6  160 110 3.90  2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710           22.8   4  108  93 3.85  2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive       21.4   6  258 110 3.08  3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout    18.7   8  360 175 3.15  3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant              18.1   6  225 105 2.76  3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

---

Or use `rename_at`

```
map(Data, ~ {
    datamap_sub <- datamap %>% 
                         filter(col_name %in% names(.x))
   .x %>%
     rename_at(vars(datamap_sub$col_name), ~ datamap_sub$VAR)
   })
```

#### data

```
datamap <- data.frame(col_name = c('Sepal.Length', 'Species', 'mpg',
      'wt'), VAR = c('SL', 'Sp', 'mpg_new', 'wt_new'))
Data <- list(head(iris), head(mtcars))
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried `rename` method, I got error message `Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist. x Column `CHCST` doesn't exist.`.  `datamap` contain all variables that I need to keep and rename from all data.frames in the list`datasets`. But not every data.frame has all the variables.

Comment: Wonderful! Could you also tell me where did I do wrong in my old codes? and also what `!!!` means?

Comment: @Stataq I think you need a `{}` within the `map` to block

Comment: Where should I add `{}`? Thanks

Comment: @Stataq It would be similar to that in my post after the `~` and before the last `)`

Comment: I tried `Data2 <- map(Data, function(.x) {.x<-.x %>%
             for( i in 1:nrow(datamap)){
  if(datamap$col_name[i] %in% names(.x)){
    names(.x)[names(.x) == datamap$col_name[i]] <- datamap$VAR[i];
  } 
}}
)` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Stataq you have used `.x %>%...` which shouldn't be there

Comment: @Stataq try `map(Data, ~  { 
       for( i in 1:nrow(datamap)){  
     if(datamap$col_name[i] %in% names(.x)){ 
      names(.x)[names(.x) == datamap$col_name[i]] <- datamap$VAR[i]
      }
      }
       .x} )`

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use `~`, how could I rewrite following codes `Data <- map(datasets, function(.x) .x <-.x %>% select(any_of(datamap$col_name)))`? This one works. I just want o know how to use `~`. Many thanks.

Comment: @Stataq The issue with `select` is that you are selecting a subset of columns and updating your `.x` data.  It is just a compact way of writing `function(.x)` instead it would be `~` and the default lamdba is `.x` here